# PHP error get value from database

Tags: php, database, get

I have php script like this

```
   $query = "select * where userid = 'agusza' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $result;
}
```

when I execute, the result like this

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where userid = 'agusza'' at line 1
```

But when I run that sql in sqlserver, it running well
Anybody has solution ?

Comment: You have two single quote marks in the error

Comment: **Warning** The `mysql_` functions have been depreciated. Please try not to use them in new code. Look into switching to `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = "select * from table_name where userid = 'agusza' ";
```

See the corrections I have made. You haven't used the right syntax for [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) query

Answer (score 2):

You didn't select a table using `FROM`. Without that, it does not know which table you are selecting data from.

You should also stop using `mysql` as it is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` as they are safer.

You are also echoing the wrong variable in your `while` loop, try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$query = "select * from table where userid = 'agusza'";

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're not telling which table SQL should look in.
You should format your query like so:

```
select * from `TableName` where userid='agusza'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query below you doesnt state the database table where you should get that data using `FROM`

```
 $query = "select * where userid = 'agusza' "; // instead of this
$query = "select * FROM declaredtable where userid = 'agusza' "; used this
```